# Facebook getinfo affiliation to retrieve college only?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

im trying to use facebook's api command `users.getInfo` to retrieve the user's (if exists) college. Here's what i got so far. It isnt correct, but i believe i am close:

```
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$college = $facebook->api_client->users_getInfo($uid, user_education_history [type="college");
```

For reference, refer here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Trying to be precise will exclude a lot of results. I would guess that many colleges aren't registered as colleges/universities. (Most of the world exclusively uses the word "university"; in some places college means preparatory or high school.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using some old methods here. The `education_history` fields have been deprecated as has the RestAPI which has the `user.getInfo` method.

A more future proof method would be to use FQL:

```
$fql = 'SELECT education FROM user WHERE uid = me()';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
               'method' => 'fql.query',
               'query' => $fql,
               ));
$schools = $ret_obj['data']['education'];
$colleges = array();
foreach ($schools as $s) {
   if ('College' == $s['type'])
      $colleges[] = $s['school']['name'];
}
```

Comment: So how can display the first college in the $college[] array?